# which is better a sram 11 speed or shimano 10 speed FD with shimano 105 11speed groupset

Tags: road-bike, shimano, sram, front

I have bought an 11 speed shimano 105 groupset, unfortunately the 11 speed FD does not fit my bike (It is an Airnimal Chamelion).  Therefore I have a choice of Sram 11 speed FD or Shimano 105 10speed ?

please advise which is best?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @chris. You will need to define your criteria for best, for anyone to have any hope of helping you!

Comment: A picture of the offending FD and of the attachment area of the bike would be helpful!

Comment: FD come in two standardised forms: either bolt-on or clamp-on. Most likely a SRAM FD will not work together with a Shimano groupset (different cable pull)

Comment: @andy256 - Surprisingly, I think despite the way this question is worded (it could be more objective), I think there is actually an objective correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you should be using a 11 speed Shimano road FD with a 11 speed road Shimano shifter. SRAM will have cable pull issues.

[According to Zinn](http://velonews.competitor.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-10-11-speed-drivetrain-component-compatibility_362722), "a Shimano 11-speed shifter will not work well with a 10-speed front derailleur because the 11-speed shifter is designed to actuate the longer lever arm of Shimano 11-speed front derailleurs." so that cuts out the old days where you didn't have to match the front shifter speeds with the front derailleur.

So, you need to find the right Shimano 11 speed front derailleur for your frame (you're looking for ["Shimano 105 5800 Braze-On Front Derailleur"](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/road/1051/fd-5800-l.html) (Shimano FD-5800-L) since the [Airnimal Chameleon](http://airnimal.eu/products/chameleon/performance-sport/) seems to have a Braze On FD).

Comment: Good work @Batman :-)